# Automatically convert function signatures into Python dataclasses

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-dataclasses

Given a Python function, e.g.

```py
def foo(a: int, b: str, c: float = 2.0) -> None:
    ...
```

Is it possible to automatically convert its signature, i.e. the `a: int, b: str c: float = 2.0` part into a dataclass?
In this example, I would like to automatically create the following dataclass based on `foo()`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class FooArgs:
    a: int
    b: str
    c: float = 2.0
```

The goal is to be able to call the function based on the dataclass, i.e.

```py
args = FooArgs(a=1, b="bar", c=3.0)
foo(**asdict(args))
```

Is there maybe some fancy metaclass or introspection magic that can do this?

Comment: Take a look at `inspect.signature()`. From that you should be able to define the corresponding dataclass.

Comment: Suggestion above is fully correct, you're unlikely to get anything better. However, beware that it will remain opaque to `mypy` unless you write your own plugin.

Comment: care to explain why this could be useful?
(looks like antipattern?)

Comment: It's meant for situations where a function (from some third party API) is called deep down in the code using configuration defined somewhere else. An example would be a training function for some ML model. Converting the signature into a dataclass serves two purposes: i) the parameters can be passed around in a single object as opposed to passing around 10+ values between several functions and ii) in contrast to dicts, dataclasses enable static checks for the configuration at definition time.

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike, thanks for pointing out the `mypy` limitation. Static checks are actually what I was after (otherwise I could just use a dict), so it sounds like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.
A perfect working version, taking in account all the possible parameter types (mandatory, keyword only, etc...) will be hard, if straightforward, to craft - as there are several possibilities.

Nonetheless, for the simple cases, it is a matter of transferring the annotations and default values of a function call to a programatic `type` call.

```
import dataclasses, inspect

def mkcls(func):
    parameters = inspect.signature(func).parameters
    annotations = foo.__annotations__.copy()
    annotations.pop("return", None)
    parameters = {par_name: par.default for par_name, par in parameters.items() if par.default is not inspect._empty}
    name = func.__name__.capitalize()
    cls = type(name, (), {"__annotations__": annotations, **parameters})
    return dataclasses.dataclass(cls)
```

This code could be a oneliner - but we already take care of one, albeit common, special case that is taking in account the default parameters and include those as default value for fields in the dataclass. Without that feature, the code would even not need using `inspect.signature`.

And on the REPL we get:

```
In [40]: def foo(a: int, b: str, c: float = 2.0) -> None:
    ...:     ...
    ...: 

In [41]: Foo = mkcls(foo)

In [42]: f = Foo(0,1)

In [43]: f
Out[43]: Foo(a=0, b=1, c=2.0)

In [44]: dataclasses.asdict(f)
Out[44]: {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2.0}
```

As stated in the comments, however, this approach won't fit `mypy` or any other static type checker: this is purely runtime code, and there is nothing the static type checkers can know about the generated classes. Static type analyses is capped and *will* be capped by its very nature, not being able to cover the full capabilities of a dynamic language.

Comment: Thanks! This is technically what I asked for, though after seeing the `mypy` limitations that have been pointed out, I realize that static typechecking is ultimately what I wanted (otherwise I could just use a dict). But it makes sense that this conversion is a little too dynamic to work with that.

Comment: You could actually modify the code to run with a special CLI arguent to generate .py files for your dynamic classes - this way you would not have to write the classes by hand. The generated .py files could be static checked.

Comment: Nice addition, your comment regarding pre-runtime code generation looks very promising and deserves place in the answer itself. Useful especially when this thing is sorta internal (not a public package) - just one extra CI step. (However, it's very close to mypy plugin writing, alternatively you can construct a dataclass there)